# Stop Symfony form from redirecting after submit

Tags: javascript, php, forms, symfony

I have a form that is rendered in a pop-up. When the form is submitted and valid, the data is saved and I'm redirected to the route of the form. How could I stop that redirection? I don't want to render another page, my goal is closing the pop-up after a valid submit.

```
public function addFeedbackAction(Request $request)
 {
   $view = View::create();

   $feedback = new Feedback();
   $feedbackService = $this->get('main.feedback.service');
   $form = $this->createForm(new FeedbackType(), null, ['action' => 'feedback']);
   $form->handleRequest($request);

   if ($form->isValid()) {
       $formData = $form->getData();
       $feedbackService->create($formData, $feedback);

       return null;
   }
   $view
     ->setData($form)
     ->setTemplateData($form)
     ->setTemplate('MainBundle:Modals:feedback.html.twig');

   return $view;
```

Comment: the question is not clear really. It is Symfony's issue at all? Send the form asynchronously via AJAX, and then to close the pop-up on a valid form submit...

Comment: Please post your JavaScript code. It should use something like `e.preventDefault();` or `return false;` in order to submit the post though AJAX without changing the current page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch submit event with Javascript.

You can find an exemple using JQuery here:
https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 0):

Send data using AJAX

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "yourControllerHere",
        data: form.serialize(),
        beforeSend: function() {
            //TODO: Loading
        },
        error: function( xhr){

        },
        success: function( data ){          

         }
    });
```

Then you can process what you gonna do in success: function (data)